# eb deploy always fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a ruby env on amazon elastic beanstalk, but when I try to deploy my rails app from command line using `eb deploy` I get this error:

```
  Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
  installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
  users on this machine.
  You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories. For help
  installing git, please refer to GitHub's tutorial at
  https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2015-08-09T15:50:38.513Z] INFO  [4217]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh] : Activity failed.
[2015-08-09T15:50:38.513Z] INFO  [4217]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2015-08-09T15:50:38.513Z] INFO  [4217]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2015-08-09T15:50:38.514Z] INFO  [4217]  - [CMD-AppDeploy] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-AppDeploy failed.
```

So, shall I install git at amazon instance bash directly? will this effect autoscaling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fixed this, but you need to tell Elastic Beanstalk to install `git`.

In the root directory of your project, add a folder called `.ebextensions`.

Create a file inside that folder called (something like) `install_git.config` (the `.config` is important).

Add the following lines to that file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Then redeploy your application, and you shouldn't see that error anymore.